# android set button background programmatically

Tags: android, button

I would like to know how to set the button color programatically?
I have coded the following but fails:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: what effect are you trying to get? A plain red rectangle with no additional effects? If not you're going to need some sort of drawable to achieve what your after, either a png (9patch) or something defined in xml. The system has no built in way to make a button that looks like a normal button except a different color. You'll have to provide your own resource unless you are looking for just a plain single colored rectangle.

Comment: actually what i am doing is that out of a table of 12 buttons, the program would randomly select 6 of them to fill in defined text. I would like these 6 buttons to change into another different color. In this regards, it cannot be done in the xml part but just be programmatically. I have already defined some xml (first unselected is plain green round color, if selected i wish it become plain red round color) If in this way, can it be done?

Comment: Right but you either need to have a red button image like a 9patch png, or you'll need to define a red button shape in xml. If you simply change the background color to red you are going to end up with a plain red rectangle not something that looks like a normal button.

Comment: yes u are correct i have modified and it reli gives out a plain red rectangle that even cannot pressed!! I have already separately defined red_button_xml, how could that be incorporated to the Activity? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you'll want `Button.setBackgroundResource()` instead of `setBackgroundColor()`

Comment: android:backgroundTint="@color/button_background_color" https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-button-in-android-using-colorstatelist/

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`R.color.red` is an ID (which is also an `int`), but is not a color.

Use one of the following instead:

```
// If you're in an activity:
Button11.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
// OR, if you're not: 
Button11.setBackgroundColor(Button11.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Or, alternatively:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // From android.graphics.Color
```

Or, for more pro skills:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000); // 0xAARRGGBB
```

Comment: How do i set different colors for more than one button which is programmatically created ?

Comment: But it erases all styles, like borders or rounded corners. So it sets color for button area in fact, not button color like OP requested.

Comment: Consider that `getColor()` is deprecated now. Use `ContextCompat` http://stackoverflow.com/a/32149275/1358777

Answer (score 49):

Old thread, but learned something new, hope this might help someone.

If you want to change the background color but retain other styles, then below might help.

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: `setColorFilter` only sets a tint to the existing background. It doesn't set a new background colour.

Comment: If you are using material style raised button, this is what will work. Not `Button.setBackgroundColor()`.

Comment: It's 2017 now and it is still sooo ugly to write this whole bunch of boilerplate in order to set the color from resource...

Comment: Why use `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` instead of `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC`? Won't the former just mix in with the existing color?

Answer (score 9):

The answer you're looking for in **2020 and beyond**:

- `setColorFilter(color, mode)` is **deprecated since API 29** ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56716093/12787264))
- `button.setBackgroundColor(color)` messes with the button style

Now the proper way to set a buttons color is using `BlendModeColorFilter()` ([see documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendModeColorFilter)).

**Usage:**

```kotlin
btn.background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.MULTIPLY)
```

**If you work with older APIs too:**

```kotlin
fun setButtonColor(btn: Button, color: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29)
        btn.background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.MULTIPLY)
    else
        btn.background.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
}
```

---

*Please **vote to help others finding this answer** - it took me quite a while figuring this out ^^*

Comment: Your method will work IF AND ONLY IF the original color of the button is white. This is due to the fact that MULTIPLY method takes into account the source color.

Comment: This works, but not if a button is styled in the your `xml` with `style=?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle`.

Comment: this is not working for me! It still pulls the default color set on styles.xml

Answer (score 6):

You can set your desired color to the button programmatically like:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.parseColor("#738b28"));
```

Also you can give the text color for a button like:

```
Button11.setTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: `btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#97a0ad"));` also works

Answer (score 3):

I have found that Android Studio gives me a warning that `getColor()` is deprecated when trying to do this:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))
```

So I found doing the method below to be the simple, up-to-date solution:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red))
```

You want to avoid hard-coding in the color argument, as it is considered bad code style.

Edit: After using `setBackgroundColor()` with my own button, I saw that the internal button padding expanded. I couldn't find any way of changing it back to having both height and width set to "wrap_content". Maybe its a bug.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202256/6030520

Answer (score 1):

For not changing the size of button on setting the background color:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(button.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

this didn't change the size of the button and works with the old android versions too.

Answer (score 1):

Using **setBackgroundColor()** affects the style.
So, declare a new style of the same properties with respect to the previous button, with a a different color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/green"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Now, use OnClick method.

```
location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            location.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);

        }
    });
```

this changes the button but looks similar to changing the background.

Answer (score 1):

Further from @finnmglas, the Java answer as of 2021 is:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29)
        btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.MULTIPLY));
    else
        btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
```

Sets the background color for this view.
Parameters: color the color of the background

`R.color.red` is a reference generated at the compilation in gen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for the button color without getting effected the style if used any

```
 yourbtnid.background.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, yourcolor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of the above answers `setColorFilter`, `setBackgroundColor`,`colorFilter` and so on, but nothing actually worked, all I was getting was a default color.

What worked for me was to use the `backgroundTintList` like this:

```
myButton.backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.red)
```

Or

```
myButton.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED)
```