# change button background color using if-else in android

Tags: android

I am in new in android development.
I want to change my button background through java coding in Android.

[image]

What I want is when I click button it turns to yellow and white(both male-female button)click after click.

Comment: Add ur code what u have tried so far

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector This may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android set button background programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842447/android-set-button-background-programmatically)

Comment: Google keywords: `android custom radiobutton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your need to bind your button in activity like this

```
btnMale=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMale);
btnFemale=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFemale);
```

than `setOnClickListener()` of our button like this

```
btnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //btnMale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);// change background your button like this

            btnMale.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorPrimary));// use this to set color as background 

            btnFemale.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default;);// use this to set color as background 
        }
    });



btnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        btnFemale.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorPrimary));// use this to set color as background 

        btnMale.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default;);// use this to set color as background 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button buttonMale = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_male);
    Button buttonFemale = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_female);

    buttonMale.setOnClickListener(getGenderOnClickListener(buttonFemale));
    buttonFemale.setOnClickListener(getGenderOnClickListener(buttonMale));
}

private Consumer<View> getGenderOnClickListener(View other) {
    return view -> {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        other.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

// OR, if you're not:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(Button11.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Or, alternatively:

`Button11.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` // From android.graphics.Color
Or, for more pro skills:

`Button11.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);` // 0xAARRGGBB

Answer (score 0):

Based On @Simon Schiller answer:
For Multiple text views on click listener (like tabview UI)

```
val TYPE_DEFAULT_DRAWABLE = R.drawable.background_button_default
val TYPE_SELECTED_DRAWABLE = R.drawable.background_button_selected

val TYPE_SELECTED_STYLE: Int = R.style.ButtonTertiaryForSelected
val TYPE_DEFAULT_STYLE: Int = R.style.ButtonTertiaryForDefault


private fun getOnClickListener(other: List<AppCompatTextView>): View.OnClickListener {
    return View.OnClickListener { view ->
        (view as AppCompatTextView).setBackgroundResource(TYPE_SELECTED_DRAWABLE)
        (view as AppCompatTextView).setTextAppearance(TYPE_SELECTED_STYLE)
        for (i in other.indices) {
            other[i].setBackgroundResource(TYPE_DEFAULT_DRAWABLE)
            other[i].setTextAppearance(TYPE_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        }

    }
}
```