# how to make buttons align at the middle? android studio

Tags: android, user-interface

how do I make those buttons stay align at the middle? this is my interface.

[image]

here is my following code. I shouldn't use margin. is there any way to make it align at the middle?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Db_New"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="NEW" />

                <Button

                    android:id="@+id/Db_Save"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="SAVE" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Db_Print"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="PRINT" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Db_Back"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="BACK" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is already staying in bottom. Only What I need it make it to look better. please help. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

How to make the white space gone?

[image]

Comment: you have pasted only the code for buttons.can post the full code ?.

Comment: I wanted to put full code, but it keep saying I put mostly code... @Sabarinathan

Comment: @Sabarinathan actually that is enough

Comment: @LeonZaii do you strictly want to use TableLayout only?

Comment: Ya. It looks more align...  @mobiledev

Comment: @LeonZaii check my answer. You don't need to use TableLayout to keep the views more align. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. I have used `LinearLayout`. Use this code to align your buttons.

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Db_New"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="NEW" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Db_Print"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="PRINT" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/Db_Save"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="SAVE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Db_Back"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="BACK" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wow, like this also works. But the buttons look a bit small.

Comment: @LeonZaii small in terms of height ?. If that is the case use height as "match_parent"  instead of "wrap_content"

Comment: Okay. Thanks for helping me @Umair

Comment: @LeonZaii happy to help. Happy coding :)

Comment: Can you help me to check the latest problem? @Umair

Comment: @LeonZaii sure what is the latest problem. ?

Comment: I have updated the latest problem above, how to make it stick together instead of separate with white space... XD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181054/discussion-between-umair-and-leon-zaii).

Comment: friend, I changed the color already. But when the button is disable. the color still the same, where to change color ? @Umair

Comment: @LeonZaii when you disable the button then you can change the button color in code. put an if else condition and set the background through code in that if./else condition.

Comment: can I use if else at XML ? @Umair

Comment: @LeonZaii no you cannot :)

Comment: So where to put if and else to change the color haha?

Comment: write if(Db_Save.isEnabled()){how to type background change color? }

Comment: @LeonZaii take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842447/android-set-button-background-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:stretchColumns="*"` and set your buttons width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Db_New"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="NEW" />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/Db_Save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="SAVE" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Db_Print"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="PRINT" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Db_Back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="BACK" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use RelativeLayout instead of TableLayout.
Like this.

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <newButton /> -> gravity:center and width:match_parent
  <saveButton /> -> alignParentsRight:true
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add replace `android:layout_width="250dp"` button code with

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

**It will center all the `Button` with fixed width.**

Answer (score 0):

As we know `TableRow` is a child of `LinearLayout`, So it is possible to do what you want using LinearLayout attribute `android:layout_weight` so we should have sth like:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="new"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="save"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:weightSum="2">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="print"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="back"/>
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Db_New"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="NEW" 
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/Db_Save"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="SAVE"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Db_Print"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="PRINT"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Db_Back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="BACK"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```