# setColorFilter is deprecated on API29

Tags: android

I use the following line to change the color of a VectorDrawable:

`mydrawable.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)`

This works nice, though it is now deprecated. The documentation suggests that I use:

`mydrawable.getBackground().setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP))`

Though, `BlendModeColorFilter` is only available on API29. After examining the source of the deprecated method, I have realized that it calls:

`new PorterDuffColorFilter()`

So, I went ahead and used:

`mydrawable.getBackground().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP))`

The coloring worked. Is this the right replacement for the deprecated method or I must use BlendModeColorFilter on API29?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use conditional logic to check if the user’s device is on API 29 and above and use that color filter and use the former code you used if the condition is not met.

Comment: @Edric, that you for the reply. Yes, I can check, but that requires making that check for over 100 instances or performing the coloring on a static method then linking it to all instances. If using PorterDuffColorFilter is right, I can do a batch replace easy.

Comment: If you are simply applying a solid color over a drawable without doing any transformation, then you could also tint the drawable, either using: `DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color)`, or directly from xml, for `ImageView`s for example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @AndyRes. I appreciate it. Though, I do not apply a tint, I replace the color completely. I create a single VectorDrawable and I color it with different colors based on the activity.

Comment: OK..  I don't see why that wouldn't work. From documentation: `setTint() 
  -  a Drawable's drawing content will be blended together with its tint
     before it is drawn to the screen. This functions similarly to
     {@link #setColorFilter(int, PorterDuff.Mode)}.`

Comment: Just a note for anyone regarding `tinting` vs `replacing` a color.  If you tint a drawable that is 100% white using the `MULTIPLY` blend mode you are essentially doing the same thing as "replacing" a color.  Basic math at play here: any color multiplied by white (ex. any value multiplied by 1 is that value) is that color.

Answer (score 150):

Try this:

```
public class MyDrawableCompat {
    public static void setColorFilter(@NonNull Drawable drawable, @ColorInt int color) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP));
        } else {
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }
}
```

And this:

```
MyDrawableCompat.setColorFilter(mydrawable.getBackground(), color);
```

**UPDATE:**
Just use the latest version of the [core androidx library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#declaring_dependencies) and this code:

```
mydrawable.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the method, shmakova. I appreciate it. That is what I would have to go for if I cannot verify that `new PorterDuffColorFilter()` works properly. In using that, I would have to manually replace every entry and I have over 100 entries. I am hoping someone would shed some light on `new PorterDuffColorFilter()`

Comment: Or `drawable.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)` with a single line of code

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian you are right. this is the correct answer. Doing an if/else will still show up warnings in the build logs.

Comment: Some of the `BlendModeCompat` values are actually marked to require a high API, while the `PorterDuff` don't. Example is `MULTIPLY` . How come?

Comment: @androiddeveloper did you find any solution for `MULTIPLY`??

Comment: @VivekThummar See here my conversation with Google about this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202172888

Answer (score 77):

Use `androidx.core:core:1.2.0` or `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0`.

```
// Java
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.2.0'
// Kotlin
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
```

And this:

```
drawable.setColorFilter(BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP))
```

Comment: Be careful using this alternative.  I tried this first, but the results didn't match `mydrawable.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)` when using the `Multiply` blend mode.

This solution seems to work the best and maintain the same expected visual results:
`mydrawable.getBackground().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY))`

Comment: @BrianBegun  
Thank you for the notice!
That was certainly true when I read the source code of `BlendModeUtils.obtainPorterDuffFromCompat`.
Sorry.

Apparently it seems to be the same behavior as `BlendModeCompat.MODULATE`.  
The mapping was as follows.  
`case MODULATE: return PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY;`  

[BlendModeUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/core/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/graphics/BlendModeUtils.java#131)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clarifying @WataruMukainakano.  That's weird that they are mapping `MODULATE` to `MULTIPLY`.  Not sure I understand why the did that.  Either way, thank you for filling in that gap.  Much appreciated.

Comment: One more thing to add.  I took a look at the source code for BlendModeUtils (located here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/core/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/graphics/BlendModeUtils.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F&autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F

It appears that `MULTIPLY` maps to `MULTIPLY` for API29 (only) using `BlendMode` otherwise for all other APIs `MODULATE` maps to `MULTIPLY` using `PorterDuff.Mode`.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!
I was curious about it, so I read the Android documentation and Javadoc.
And as I found out, `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` and `BlendModeCompat.MODULATE` seem to do the same filtering.  

Doc:  
[PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode#MULTIPLY)  
[BlendModeCompat.MODULATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendMode#MODULATE)  

Javadoc:  
`* <p> \ (\ alpha_ {out} = \ alpha_ {src} * \ alpha_ {dst} \) </ p>`
`* <p> \ (C_ {out} = C_ {src} * C_ {dst} \) </ p>`

Comment: Is google have a contract with someone to bother us? :| why it made everything complicated?

Comment: Super weird that it doesn't work on `BottomNavigationView`! `navigation.background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(android.R.color.black, BlendModeCompat. MULTIPLY)` or any other Mode.

Comment: Both `MULTIPLY` and `MODULATE` (that you guys say that are the same) require a relatively high API. How come? It's supposed to be compatible with older versions of Android. What should I use instead of ` PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`?

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to @shmakova I added a solution for Kotlin.

```
import android.graphics.BlendMode
import android.graphics.BlendModeColorFilter
import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi

fun Drawable.setColorFilter(color: Int, mode: Mode = Mode.SRC_ATOP) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(color, mode.getBlendMode())
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        setColorFilter(color, mode.getPorterDuffMode())
    }
}

// This class is needed to call the setColorFilter 
// with different BlendMode on older API (before 29).
enum class Mode {
    CLEAR,
    SRC,
    DST,
    SRC_OVER,
    DST_OVER,
    SRC_IN,
    DST_IN,
    SRC_OUT,
    DST_OUT,
    SRC_ATOP,
    DST_ATOP,
    XOR,
    DARKEN,
    LIGHTEN,
    MULTIPLY,
    SCREEN,
    ADD,
    OVERLAY;

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    fun getBlendMode(): BlendMode =
        when (this) {
            CLEAR -> BlendMode.CLEAR
            SRC -> BlendMode.SRC
            DST -> BlendMode.DST
            SRC_OVER -> BlendMode.SRC_OVER
            DST_OVER -> BlendMode.DST_OVER
            SRC_IN -> BlendMode.SRC_IN
            DST_IN -> BlendMode.DST_IN
            SRC_OUT -> BlendMode.SRC_OUT
            DST_OUT -> BlendMode.DST_OUT
            SRC_ATOP -> BlendMode.SRC_ATOP
            DST_ATOP -> BlendMode.DST_ATOP
            XOR -> BlendMode.XOR
            DARKEN -> BlendMode.DARKEN
            LIGHTEN -> BlendMode.LIGHTEN
            MULTIPLY -> BlendMode.MULTIPLY
            SCREEN -> BlendMode.SCREEN
            ADD -> BlendMode.PLUS
            OVERLAY -> BlendMode.OVERLAY
        }

    fun getPorterDuffMode(): PorterDuff.Mode =
        when (this) {
            CLEAR -> PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR
            SRC -> PorterDuff.Mode.SRC
            DST -> PorterDuff.Mode.DST
            SRC_OVER -> PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER
            DST_OVER -> PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER
            SRC_IN -> PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
            DST_IN -> PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN
            SRC_OUT -> PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT
            DST_OUT -> PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT
            SRC_ATOP -> PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP
            DST_ATOP -> PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP
            XOR -> PorterDuff.Mode.XOR
            DARKEN -> PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN
            LIGHTEN -> PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN
            MULTIPLY -> PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
            SCREEN -> PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN
            ADD -> PorterDuff.Mode.ADD
            OVERLAY -> PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY
        }
}
```

Use it as usually:

```
toolbar?.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, color)) /* 1 */
progressBar.indeterminateDrawable.setColorFilter(color, Mode.SRC_IN) /* 2 */
```

I tried to call `setColorFilter` with both `BlendMode` and `PorterDuff.Mode` parameters (like `drawable.setColorFilter(color, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)`), but that led to a runtime exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/graphics/BlendMode;

So, we can call any method with [BlendMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendMode) only starting from SDK version 29 (it was added there). I had to create `setColorFilter` with `Mode` parameter.

Comment: I have tested this in a large project and it works successful. I have created a seperate Kotlin file and calls it from there, this essentially created a alternateve setColorFilter to for the original that runs when these parementers are met.

Comment: @TitanKing, thank you for your feedback! Do you still need to use this extension method? You know, I have been using it for some months, but then turned to Wataru Mukainakano solution.

Answer (score 2):

[`PorterDuffColorFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter) was added in API level 1 and it's not deprecated, in addition `PorterDuffColorFilter` is a subclass of `ColorFilter`. You may use it as you did with no problems as `setColorFilter` parameter is of type `ColorFilter` and it does not require you to pass a `BlendModeColorFilter`. The are many reasons why the documentation may suggests `BlendModeColorFilter`. Maybe they plan on deprecating `PorterDuffColorFilter` in the future (as of 2021 it is still not deprecated) or maybe it just performs better, who knows... The point is that you used it correctly. If you want to safeguard against your code breaking down because `PorterDuffColorFilter` suddenly got deprecated and removed then you should do what many others have suggested and add a Version check. If you are not worried about that then you don't have to do it but you will have to keep an eye out for any future changes.

But all in all as of 2021 your code will work on all versions.

Regards

NOTE: `setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)` is deprecated this answer is only relevant to `setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter)`

Comment: I got a null pointer Exception because of this porterDuff on android 11, tried to get background of a toast to customize the color, but it crashed.

Comment: Custom toast views are deprecated in Android 11 mate. It has nothing to do with PorterDuff. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#getView()

Comment: true. getView returns null. i targeted my toast BGcolor customizations for android 9 and below. only the message for android 10+

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension function to set tint programmatically:

```
/**
 * Sets a tint color on the drawable of the image view with the specified color.
 *
 * @param color The color to use for the color filter.
 */
fun ImageView.setTintColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
    val colorInt = ContextCompat.getColor(context, color)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        drawable?.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(colorInt, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP)
    } else {
        @Suppress("deprecation")
        drawable?.setColorFilter(colorInt, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
imageView.setTintColor(R.color.green)
```

Comment: Instead of BlendMode.SRC_ATOP , BlendMode.COLOR worked for me

Answer (score -2):

BlendMode Filters may require higher API to be working.

check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/BlendModeCompat#ENUM_VALUE:HUE) to know more