# drawable.setColorFilter marked as deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, drawable, android-tablayout

Compiler gives me that setColorFilter is deprecated!

```
 tab?.icon?.setColorFilter(
                ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.colorLogoGrey),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
            )
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable), `setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)` is actually **deprecated** from **API level 29**.
Probably in your gradle file you have:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
```

By the way you can use `setColorFilter` with an instance of `BlendModeColorFilter`:

```
tab?.icon?.colorFilter(BlendModeColorFilter(R.color.colorAccent, BlendMode.SRC_IN))
```

Comment: This will crash on lower API level, use MyDrawableCompat  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716093/setcolorfilter-is-deprecated-on-api29/56717316

Answer (score 2):

Just use BlendModeColorFilterCompat, to avoid crash on old Android APIs.

```
BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(ContextCompat.getColor(yourContext, yourColor), BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)
```