# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/BlendModeColorFilter;

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

This app crashes when I am running it on the emulator. The line that causes it to crash is `v.getBackground().setColorFilter`.

But, there is no problem when testing the app on an actual device.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                v.getBackground().setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(0xe0f47521, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP));
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: [The `BlendModeColorFilter` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendModeColorFilter) wasn't introduced until API level 29. Trying to use it on previous versions will throw that Exception.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm just curious, why does it not have the same error when debugging on an actual device? It only crashes when using the emulator.

Comment: I would have to guess that the device is API level 29 or above, but the emulator is an older version.

Comment: @MikeM. You are correct. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned previously, BlendModeColorFilter wasn't introduced until API level 29. An error should be thrown at build time if you ask me but I digress...

The best solution in my opinion is to go with [BlendModeColorFilterCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/BlendModeColorFilterCompat) available in recent androidx core releases as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717316/8053848).

Which would give:

```
v.getBackground().setColorFilter(BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(-0x1f0b8adf, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP));
```