# setColorFilter(int,Mode) is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-layout, colors, drawable

I have been using this method: public void setColorFilter `(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)` but I have seen that it is deprecated. In the Android documentation I have seen that I can use this instead:

```
This method was deprecated in API level 29.
use setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter) with an instance of BlendModeColorFilter
```

I have tried to solve it but I have not achieved to use thes newer methods. I have also seen other posts as duplicated but they were kotlin version and not java version as this one. So, how could I implement it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this thread answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716093/setcolorfilter-is-deprecated-on-api29/56717316#56717316

Comment: @DorianFeyerer I have see that answer before, but is that answer Java actually? The answer given is using `mydrawable.colorFilter` and the `colorFilter` is not recognized in my project, so that is why I thought that maybe it was only working for Kotlin that answer.

Comment: That's just a Kotlin way of using a setter function like a property - so instead of writing `myDrawable.setColorFilter(...)` you can write `myDrawable.colorFilter = ...`. It's still really calling `setColorFilter()` so you can just do it that way from Java. The linked answer is basically showing you how to create a `BlendModeColorFilter` to pass to `setColorFilter`, like the warning is asking you to do

Comment: @cactustictacs myDrawable.colorFilter is not recognized I don´t know why, the colorFiletr is highlited in red

Comment: Hover the mouse over it and it'll tell you why. Are you using a recent `androidx.core` library version like the linked answer says? Did you import `BlendModeColorFilter`? (It should do it for you if you put the cursor on the name and click the lightbulb for a quick fix, or if you partially type the name and let it autocomplete)

Comment: Do I need to add every dependency of that link? I have added everyone but it is still highlighted in red and when I put the cursor on the name, the following error is shown: Cannot resolve symbol 'colorFilter'.