# Alternative to setColorFilter(int,Mode)

Tags: java, android, filter, imageview

I have seen that the following method is deprecated : `public void setColorFilter (int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)`. In the Android documentation I have seen the following recommendation:

```
This method was deprecated in API level 29.
use setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter) with an instance of BlendModeColorFilter
```

I am trying to replace that method to a non-deprecated method but I have not achieved it. I have seen similar posts to this one but they are kotlin version. How could I replace this deprecated method for a non-deprecated method in Java?

Thanks

edit:

What I had using the deprecated method:

```
 public static void setcol(TextView dLabel) {
       
dLabel.getBackground().setColorFilter(color,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}
```

what I have changed to use non-deprecated method that is apparently working to replace the above deprecated method:

```
 public static void setcol(TextView dLabel) {
           
     dLabel.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(
                        color,
                        BlendModeCompat.SRC_OVER
                )
        );
}
```

Comment: This looks like Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717316/2649154

Comment: @gioravered  I have already seen that post, in that post, `mydrawable.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)'` .The "colorFilter" is highlighted in read, it says unresolved reference of colorFilter. I have also added the dependencies that in that post is said to add, this is why I made this post...

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works in Java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setcol(TextView dLabel) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        dLabel.getBackground().setColorFilter(
            color, 
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
        );
    } else {
        dLabel.getBackground().setColorFilter(
            BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(
                color,
                BlendModeCompat.MULTIPLY
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Change the color to you desired *color* and the *some_drawable_id* to your drawable.

Comment: If I can acces my drawable already in the file that I am working on, I mean, to access the drawable I have the folliwing function:  ´public static void fun(TextView dLabel){dLabel.getBackground().setColorFilter(calendarProperties.getSelectionColor(),android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);} ´ so as you can see dLabel.getBackround() is my drawable already, so could I use that drawable intead of this line of code you put:                                                      ´Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.id.some_drawable_id);´

Comment: You can use any Drawable object..

Comment: Hello, I have edited the post to let you check if it is okay what I have changed. Apparently it is working perfect and doing the same as the function I had firstly (the one using the deprecated method). So could I say that `android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` is equivalent to `BlendModeCompat.SRC_OVER`? Do you think it is perfect how I implemented it using your solution and it will be working as the function with the deprecated method I had?

Comment: Changed to Multiply..

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that I could put   `BlendModeCompat.MULTIPLY`  , but the following warning appears:  > "Field requires API level 29 (current min is 21): MULTIPLY . So I am trying to look for a solution"

Comment: @Lechius - Updated answer to support lower APIs

Comment: If i don't add the line of code `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` , the deprecated warning is shown, could it be that it is shown because I am using it in the code but there won't be any problem as it won't be executed in API levels in which this method is deprecated according to the error control I made?I mean, the warning is shown because Android Studio doesn't know that I am controlling this error?, right?

Comment: You are correct. The SuppressWarnings is only for the IDEA (android studio) to know ignore this warning and has no affect on the code execution. It is a known practice when handling different API levels.