# Cannot resolve symbol 'colotFilter'

Tags: java, android, performance, android-drawable, android-filter

I have been using the following function to set color filter, but recently I have seen that it is deprecated. This was what I was using and was working fine:  `public void setColorFilter (int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)`

In order to solve that deprecated method, I have been searching for information to replace this deprecated function and I have come across with this answer: [answer that apparently replaces this deprecated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716093/setcolorfilter-is-deprecated-on-api29/56717316#56717316)

In that awnser, it says to use the following method:

```
mydrawable.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)
```

It seems to be a good solution, but my problem is that I don´t know why the "colorFilter" is highlighted in red and is not being recognized in my project by Android Studio. The following warning is shown when I hover the mouse over it:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'colorFilter'

I would appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It says "colorFilter" in the code and "colotFilter" in the warning that you posted.

Comment: @VOL yes, you are right, I have edited the question because I have wrote it wrong, the warning says "colorFilter" same as the code now. Thanks for the notice