# Android programmatically change background of Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I fail changing the background of my button in my activity. It is a basic button which a shape as a background.

In my main.xml it looks like this in my RelativeLayout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybtn"
    android:background = "@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:elevation="0dp" />
```

In my MainActivity I try to change the button like this:

```
    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

But it says:

> cannot resolve method setBackgroundColor

Comment: Check if in your import there's the line `import android.widget.Button`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android set button background programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842447/android-set-button-background-programmatically)

Comment: What is @drawable/rounded_button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Button b = ...;
int color = ...;
...
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(button, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
```

Compat libraries checks compatibility and remove most of issues that come with android fragmentation.

You can try to set background by calling compatibility library with set background color method, but I prefer and probably a common usage is to call tint methods on a components that comes from appcompat and a material design library.

Hope this helps.

BR

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the background of your drawable I guess

```
Drawable mDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable. rounded_button); 
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.RED);
```

Comment: Did not change the color

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the setBackgroundColor to setBackground.

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.mybtn); btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the setBackgroundColor to setBackground.

```
Button button= findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
```

Try this below code

```
button.setBackgroundResource(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity,this,R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can try this

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context , active ? R.drawable.gray_schedule_button : R.drawable.curved_button_shape ));
```