# Android Kotlin - Changing the background of a button programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I change the background of a button programmatically with Android using Kotlin?

Comment: Same way you do with Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842447/android-set-button-background-programmatically

Comment: try this button.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.my_color))

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to change background programmatically :

```
button.backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.yourColor)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  /// write your custome code here...
 </shape>
```

create drawable in /app/src/main/res/drawable/btn_drawable.xml
and set it as background of button.
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_drawable);

Change background on button click :

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        if(isThemeOne){
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_drawable_1);
            isThemeOne=false;
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_drawable_2);
            isThemeOne=true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this easy way for all version

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            btn.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.black))
        }else{
            btn.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))
        }
```